# Splitting a string on backtick in clojure

Tags: regex, string, clojure

I'm trying to split a string on backtick in the clojure repl, like this:

```
user> (require '[clojure.string :as str])

user> (str/split "1=/1`2=/2'" #"`'")
```

Result is:

```
["1=/1`2=/2'"]
```

In short, I'm unable to split on the backtick character. And I don't know why. How can I make this work?

p.s:Notice the apostrophe at the end of the string and in the split argument. These are auto inserted in the repl.

Comment: `(clojure.string/split "1=/1`2=/2'" #"`")` works on my local settings. I tested it against a REPL invoked by `lein repl` and Emacs/CIDER. Maybe your REPL has something wrong.

Comment: my repl do not add an auto-inserted `'`. May be it''s because of terminal emulator, you should try `rlwrap lein repl` or CIDER Repl for example.

Comment: thanks, tried it in lein repl, works allright. it's in the emacs cider repl that an extra ' is added which messes up the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `'` in your regex.

This works fine:

```
(str/split "1=/1`2=/2'" #"`")
```

Comment: thanks. true, the par-edit mode in emacs cider repl adds this extra ' apostrophe to the expression. but it works fine in lein repl.